# GWT CssResource throws NPE

Tags: gwt

I am getting strange NPE while using CssResource.
I have defined following two css classes in my css file:

```
.mainPanelStyle
{
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.titleLabelStyle
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Segoe UI Semibold;
    color: white;
}
```

Then, I defined an interface as:

```
public interface HomePanelCssResource
        extends CssResource
    {
        String mainPanelStyle();

        String titleLabelStyle();
    }
```

And added an entry into ClientBundle class as:

```
@Source( "com/myapp/homePanel/css/homePanelDefault.css" )
    HomePanelCssResource getHomePanelStyle();
```

When I use this CSS resource in class file, calling `cssResource.mainPanelStyle()` works fine. But calling `cssResource.titleLabelStyle()` throws NPE. It says "did you forget to add required dependency?".

I don't know what is wrong. Could you please help me solving this issue?

Comment: Shouldn't you put quotes around "Segoe UI Semibold" ? I can't explain the NPE (not without a stack trace), but that might be the cause.

Comment: Instead of `cssResource.titleLabelStyle()` did you mean `getHomePanelStyle.titleLabelStyle()` ? Maybe you aren't instantiating your Resource instance.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know where your error comes from, but this might help you......

This is how I defined and accessed a CssResource:

My main class:
It defines the client bundle and, and the Cssresource name.

```
interface MyClientBundler extends ClientBundle {

    public static final MyClientBundler INSTANCE =  GWT.create(MyClientBundler.class);

    //my.css and the whole packege path are allowed
    @Source("stefank/client/my.css")
    public MyResources css();
}

interface MyResources extends CssResource {
    String test();
}


public void onModuleLoad() {
    Label l = new Label("Resource Test");

    MyClientBundler.INSTANCE.css().ensureInjected(); //importaten, else the resource might not be loaded jet

    l.addStyleName(MyClientBundler.INSTANCE.css().test());

    RootPanel.get().add(l);
}
```

My css resouce (int the same packagage as the main class):

```
.test {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

This gives my label the right size and right background color.

Links:
[CssResource](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle?hl=de#CssResource)

Comment: Stefan, you rock!  Thanks for the ensureInjected()!!  It was driving me nuts.